# Jetty - httponly cookie not being saved in browser in embedded jetty 11

Tags: java, cookies, jetty, embedded-jetty, cookie-httponly

In my web app i am setting response cookies this way:

```
Cookie testCookie = new Cookie("test", "mycookie");
testCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
testCookie.setPath("/");
testCookie.setMaxAge(3600);
testCookie.setSecure(true);

response.addCookie(testCookie); // Response is of type HttpServletResponse
```

The client that is performing the requests is running in localhost.

When i look at the request in chrome, i see that cookie tab and see that the cookie was received but I cannot find this cookie in chrome when i look in the Application->Cookies tab and the other requests i do after this was done, do not send cookies.

Also, in jetty 11 i cannot seem to be able to set the SameSite attribute of the cookie.

How can i set this cookie and is it normal that an httpOnly cookie is not visible in the Application tab in chrome? How can i verify if it was set or not?

EDIT:
**Additional details**
I am running the client in https://localhost and the server is using https with a self signed certificate.
The cookie i am receiving seems corect from the response but then chrome does not seem to save it.

Comment: Did the `Set-Cookie` HTTP Response header arrive with any SameSite value specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our experience is that Chrome will reject/drop any `Set-Cookie` without a `SameSite` value set.

The behavior in Jetty 11 ...

- `jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie` has no setters/getters for "SameSite" (that's a feature of the next Servlet API release).
- By default, the `ServletContext` attribute `org.eclipse.jetty.cookie.sameSiteDefault` contains the default value for the `SameSite` cookie attribute. (use one of value `None`, `Strict`, or `Lax`).  If this attribute is unset there is no `SameSite` value provided with your cookies.
- You can configure `SameSite`, and `HttpOnly` with cookie comments in Jetty to control specific Cookie `SameSite` behavior.

Example:

```java
Cookie testCookie = new Cookie("test", "mycookie");
testCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
testCookie.setPath("/");
testCookie.setMaxAge(3600);
testCookie.setSecure(true);
testCookie.setComment("__SAME_SITE_LAX__");
// This can be __SAME_SITE_NONE__, or __SAME_SITE_STRICT__, or __SAME_SITE_LAX__

response.addCookie(testCookie);
```

When evaluating these changes in your browser, confirm that the `Set-Cookie` response header is what you want first, then look at the application tab.

Note that Chrome has tons of special rules for domain names that are IP addresses, single label domains, and reserved hostnames such as "test" or "localhost", etc.   These do not work normally for TLS/SSL, SameSite, CORs, Preflight requests, etc.   Avoid using any of these while you are testing, use a fully qualified hostname when you can, otherwise you'll be surprised by these rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I assume that what you described works with a localhost client as well? I am calling the api from localhost in https with a self signed certificate on the api. As of now, i tried this solution but i still don't see the cookie in the application tab. The header however is set correctly

Comment: Added notes about localhost (and other things)

Comment: It is fine for me to use a domain to do some major testing, but what about when i am developing the client, i am using angular in localhost and the httponly cookie is used to authenticate the user

Comment: If you are using a browser, like chrome, don't use `http://localhost/` if you want Cookies, SSL/TLS, CORs, etc to work in the way you expect.